# How programmatically via GeoMesa/Spark can I read a shapefile?

Tags: apache-spark, geomesa

I am going through the documentation https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/convert/shp.html but I cannot find a way to read shapefiles (in my case stored on S3) using GeoMesa/Spark. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

There are three broad options.

1. GeoMesa loads data into Spark via 'RDD Providers'.  The converters you linked to can be used in Spark via the ConverterRDD Provider.  (https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/spark/providers.html#converter-rdd-provider)  This may just work.
2. There is also an GeoTools DataStore RDD Provider implementation.  (https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/spark/providers.html#geotools-rdd-provider)  That could be used with the GeoTools ShapefileDataStore (https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/data/shape.html)  The work here is to line up the correct jars and parameters.
3. If you are fine with using the GeoTools Shapefile DataStore, you could use that directly in Spark to load features into memory and then sort out how to make an RDD/Dataframe.  (This is kinda skipping on the use of the RDD Provider bits.)

Comment: Because shape files are bundles of related files, they do not work well with map/reduce inputs, which are used to drive the RDD providers. The best you can do is option 3 - load up a shapefile in a single thread, then distribute/parallelize the resulting features.